# Why not look at the precision and recall of both classes combined in a classification report?

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, metrics, precision-recall

I was looking at the classification report from sklearn. I am wondering, why did they omit a potential third row with precision and recall values for both classes together?  Why were they split apart, and what's the disadvantage to considering these metrics with both classes combined?

Comment: I guess you would need to tell sklearn how to combine both classes, i.e. how to weigh the contributions of each.


E.g. equal weight for both classes? What if they're unbalanced? Weigh the contribution of each according to the number of instances where the ground truth is that class? Etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Precision and recall values for both classes together" is contained in the `classification_report` as macro averages and weighted averages for precision, recall, and f1-score.

Compare the column in `classification_report` to the values computed when calling `precision_score(y_true, y_pred)`:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score

y_true = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
y_pred = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0]

print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
print(round(precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro'), 2))
print(round(precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='weighted'), 2))
```

Running this results in the following. Notice that macro-averaged precision is 0.64 and weighted-average precision is 0.67, and both those are listed in the bottom rows of the table:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.43      0.60      0.50         5
           1       0.50      0.57      0.53         7
           2       1.00      0.57      0.73         7

    accuracy                           0.58        19
   macro avg       0.64      0.58      0.59        19
weighted avg       0.67      0.58      0.60        19

0.64
0.67
```

Comment: time for me to google what the macro is!

Comment: I avoided the "Why" question in this answer because it's a little opinionated. Briefly: most of scikit-learn is designed to be compatible with multiclass prediction, but many metrics  derived from a confusion matrix become ambiguous when extended into the multiclass setting. You'll see an example of this if you try running `precision_score` without specifying an averaging approach, it throws an error unless you pass macro/micro/weighted/etc..

Comment: This is a really great answer, and a great comment. If you have a blog or something, I'd really love to hear you expand on it. I'm sure many others would too.

Comment: Thank you! I have a paper coming out *soon*™ on a similar topic. I might write a short post, I do have a blog but haven't posted anything about this yet https://hayesall.com/blog/

Comment: just came across this excellent example of micro and macro averages for precision https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15989/micro-average-vs-macro-average-performance-in-a-multiclass-classification-settin